# How do I log out when I'm ready to leave the site?

Tags: support

First time user: I can't find where/how to log out when I'm done.

Comment: Why would anyone want to leave the site?

Comment: @Valorum - are you looking for in-universe explanation or out-of-universe?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can simply click On *Stack Exchange* (top left of your screen) then click *log out* :

[image: log out]

Then you will be asked if you want to quit all Stack Exchange communities.

Comment: Needs more [freehand red circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138031/239016).

Comment: @SQB - Needs more animated gifs

Comment: @SQB There we go. :P

Comment: @Mithrandir thanks !

Answer (score 11):

[image]